# FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT cannot be resolved to a variable in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I'm getting this error in my Android broadcast receiver code below (the last line). I don't understand why this constant isn't available in this context?

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Code to be executed after a phone reboot
        PendingIntent pi;
        AlarmManager am;

        // Read the pending_alarms table and re-create the pending intents
        List<pending_alarm> pending_alarm = new TableControllerPendingAlarm(
                context).read();

        if (pending_alarm.size() > 0) {
            int idx = 0;
            for (pending_alarm obj : pending_alarm) {

                long id = obj.id;
                String mealItemDesc = obj.alarm_desc;
                int alarmMinutes = obj.alarm_minutes;
                int alarmHours = obj.alarm_hours;
                long mealPlanId = obj.id;

                Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, obj.alarm_day);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, obj.alarm_month - 1);
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, obj.alarm_year);
                cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, obj.alarm_minutes);
                cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, obj.alarm_hours);

                Intent alarmIntent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                alarmIntent1.putExtra("meal_item_desc", obj.alarm_desc);
                alarmIntent1.putExtra("meal_id", obj.fk_meal_id);
                alarmIntent1.putExtra("pending_alarm_id", obj.fk_meal_plan_id);
                alarmIntent1.setAction(Long.toString(id));
                idx++;
                pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idx, alarmIntent1, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That flag is a constant which is not part the current class. It's part of the `PendingIntent` class.

So address it as such:

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

Comment: Thanks - that explains it perfectly, and has solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` belongs to `Intent`.

Change

```
 pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idx, alarmIntent1, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to

```
pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idx, alarmIntent1, Intent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```